# shp2pgsql not writing all the features and INSERT INTO statements written incorrectly

Tags: postgresql, shp2pgsql

My shapefile contains 2400 features. When I use `shp2pgsql` my output contains 111 `INSERT INTO` statements, so not every feature is getting written for some reason. Additionally, the SQL is written fine for about the first 100 features, but then it stops ending the `VALUES` statement with `);` like it's supposed to, so there's no closing parentheses and it produces syntax errors if I run it.

I run it like this:
`shp2pgsql -s 4326 huc8 public.huc8 > huc8.sql`

I have tried exporting my shapefile to a new shapefile just to see if it cleaned up something corrupt, but no luck there. The `shp2pgsql` tool produces no errors in the terminal when I run it. How do I fix this?